# Displaying Custom Fields in LINQ to Entity Dynamic Select

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework, linq, dynamic-linq

Let's say I have an entity `Container` with four properties: `ContainerID` (Integer), `ContainerNumber` (String), `Title` (String), and `Date` (Date).

I have a second entity called `ContainerCustomFields` that has three properties: `CustomFieldID` (Integer), `ContainerID` (Integer and Foreign Key), `FieldName` (String), `FieldContent` (String). The `ContainerCustomFields` entity stores user-defined custom fields for the `Container` entity. The data looks like this:

For Container:

```
Container
---------
ID  |     Number     |     Title     |    Date      |
=====================================================
1   |      10000     |   1st Title   |   1/12/2017  |
2   |      10543     |   2nd Title   |   1/31/2017  |
3   |      10667     |   3rd Title   |   4/12/2016  |
4   |      12889     |   4th Title   |   5/23/2012  |
```

For Custom Fields:

```
ID  |   ContainerID   |   FieldName   |    Content  |
=====================================================
1   |        1        |    Colour     |    Blue     |
2   |        1        |    Height     |    5000     |
3   |        1        |    Length     |    9100     |
4   |        4        |    Colour     |    Gray     |
```

Is it possible to return the data so it looks like this:

```
Container
---------
ID  |     Number     |     Title     |    Date      |   Colour   |  Height  |  Length  |  
====================================================================================
1   |      10000     |   1st Title   |   1/12/2017  |    Blue    |   5000   |   9100   |
2   |      10543     |   2nd Title   |   1/31/2017  |            |          |          |
3   |      10667     |   3rd Title   |   4/12/2016  |            |          |          |
4   |      12889     |   4th Title   |   5/23/2012  |    Gray    |          |          |
```

I'm able to get a list of the custom fields and their values for each container as well as select the columns that I want from the entity using a select statement. How do I combine these two statements?

```
For Each customField In _db.ContainerCustomFields
  .Where(Function(cf) cf.ContainerID = newBox.ContainerID)

returnContainers.Select(Function(c) New With 
  {.ContainerID = c.ContainerID, 
   .Number = c.ContainerNumber,
   .Title = c.Title,
   .Date = c.Date })
```

I'm using Web API 2 to return this as an anonymous type for my web application.

Comment: why must use anonymous type?

Comment: @DavidG I'm fine either C# or VB. More people are familiar with C#.

Comment: @LeiYang I'm using Web API 2 to return my results to a Kendo UI grid. There is some processing that needs to be done on the data and not all of the fields are needed.

Comment: you need to pivot the tables into sql join, I don't think C# is relevant into this. Use TSQL SP into sql server to achieve your result.

Comment: @ Nse I agree with @DavidG . I actually edited this question and suggested to remove the tag, which you rejected (by *NOT* explaining why you would like to leave this tag in). 
I really do not see the need for C# tag here, as this is a general question about LINQ.

Comment: @RonaldRink'd-fens' I'm still a little new to some of the nuances of StackOverflow's moderating system so please forgive the lack of reply. In my question there was exactly one line of VB.NET code which is simple enough that no one would have trouble substituting C# code. The proposed answer is entirely C# code with a bit of SQL thrown in so the C# tag is appropriate. LINQ queries aren't written in their own separate language, but in a .NET language (VB.NET or C#). In my opinion, since the answer is in C# if anything the VB.NET tag should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

First group into each Container, turning Fields & values into arrays within the grps:

```
var grps = from c in _db.Containers
join ccf in _db.ContainerCustomFields
    on c.ContainerID equals ccf.ContainerID
select  new 
        {ContainerId = c.ContainerID, 
         ContainerNumber= c.ContainerNumber, 
         Title = c.Title, 
         Date = c.Date, 
         FieldName = ccf.FieldName, 
         FieldContent = ccf.FieldContent}
into f
group f by f.ContainerId
into myGroup
select new
{
    ContainerId = myGroup.Key,
    ContainerNumber = myGroup.Max(d => d.ContainerNumber),
    Title = myGroup.Max(d => d.Title),
    Date = myGroup.Max(d => d.Date),
    Fields = myGroup.Select(d => d.FieldName).ToArray(),
    Values = myGroup.Select(d => d.FieldContent).ToArray()
};
```

Now find all of the Field Names that can appear:

```
var fields = from ccf in _db.ContainerCustomFields 
             group ccf by ccf.FieldName
             into grp
             select grp.Key;
```

Now create a datatable that contains columns for our containers and all possible fields:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("ContainerId", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("ContainerNumber", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
foreach(var fld in fields)
{
    dt.Columns.Add(fld, typeof(String));
}
```

Now for each group of data add a row for to our datatable and add values for each fields that are relevant:

```
foreach (var row in grps)
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ContainerId"] = row.ContainerId;
    dr["ContainerNumber"] = row.ContainerNumber;
    dr["Title"] = row.Title;
    dr["Date"] = row.Date;
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Fields.Count(); i++)
    {
        dr[row.Fields[i]] = row.Values[i];
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);    
}
```

Now you can use the data table to fill out a grid or whatever. Missing Field Values in the data table will be set to null.

Setup code I used for the database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Container
(
    ContainerID Int, 
    ContainerNumber Varchar(50), 
    Title Varchar(50), 
    [Date] Date
)

INSERT INTO Container
VALUES
(1, '10000', '1st Title', '2017-01-12'),
(2, '10543', '2nd Title', '2017-01-31'),
(3, '10667', '3rd Title', '2017-04-12'),
(4, '12889', '4th Title', '2017-05-23')


CREATE TABLE ContainerCustomFields 
(
    CustomFieldID INT, 
    ContainerID Int, 
    FieldName Varchar(50), 
    FieldContent Varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO ContainerCustomFields
VALUES
(1,1, 'Colour', 'Blue'),
(2,1, 'Height', '5000'),
(3,1, 'length', '9100'),
(4,4, 'Colour', 'Gray')
```