# SQL GROUPBY query into a LINQ to Entity query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have an SQL query that I want to turn into a LINQ to Entity query. The SQL Query is as follows:

```
SELECT [Crown2017].[dbo].[BoxCustomFields].[Name]
  FROM [Crown2017].[dbo].[Clients]
  INNER JOIN [Crown2017].[dbo].[Boxes]
  ON [Crown2017].[dbo].[Clients].[ClientID] = [Crown2017].[dbo].[Boxes].[ClientID]
  INNER JOIN [Crown2017].[dbo].[BoxCustomFields]
  ON [Crown2017].[dbo].[Boxes].[BoxID] = [Crown2017].[dbo].[BoxCustomFields].[BoxID]
  WHERE [Crown2017].[dbo].[Clients].[ClientID] = 182
  GROUP BY [Crown2017].[dbo].[BoxCustomFields].[Name]
```

How do I perform this GROUPBY query in VB.NET? So far I have the following query, but I can't select my columns in the SELECT statement.

```
_db.BoxCustomFields.Include("Box")
  .Where(Function(c) c.Box.ClientID = ClientID)
  .GroupBy(Function(cf) cf.Name)
  .Select(Function(box) New With { .BoxID = ...can't get select to work... }
```

See this question for a bit more detail. That answer works in C#, but I can't get the same thing to work in VB.NET.

[Displaying Custom Fields in LINQ to Entity Dynamic Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775610/displaying-custom-fields-in-linq-to-entity-dynamic-select)

Comment: Please you should notice that Group By will return IEnumerable<IEnumerable<BoxCustomFields>> so the select statement will take IEnumerable<BoxCustomFields> as function parameter not BoxCustomFields.

Comment: The SQL query returns only the `BoxCustomFields.Name` field which is the only one use in `GROUP BY` clause. Which maps to the LINQ grouping `Key` property, so the only thing you can put in `Select` is `box.Key`.

Comment: @Nse Sorry Group By will return IEnumerable<string, IEnumerable<BoxCustomFields>>.

Comment: Seeing the shape of your query I think you don't even need `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Try doing the select before the groupby